# Creating multiple header images when using PHP header include

Tags: php, html, css

I am creating a multipage website that uses a header include. I have a background image already set (using CSS) in a  container in my header, and I would like to use different header images for each page. However, I am not sure what the best way is to go about doing this. I am a beginner at PHP, so my skills are limited. Thanks!

Comment: can you add a unique class to the `body` element of each page? If so, you could use CSS to control which background to use, like `body.home header { background-image: url(home-header-image.jpg);` and `body.contact header { background-image: url(contact-header-image.jpg);`

Comment: My opening body tag is in my header.php (include) file, so if I add a body class, it will be added to all the pages. I have one background image that I am trying to use for all the pages, but I would like to place a different image over that for each page.
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div id="background">

Comment: what does the page that includes header.php look like? Do you have an identifier for which page you're on in that file? If so, you can set `$page = whatever-the-page-is` in that file, the in the `header.php`, assuming the image you want to appear over the background is an `img`, you can use `<img src="/<?php echo $page; ?>.jpg">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header do something like this, giving each page's `<html>` element a unique ID.

```
<!doctype html>
<html id="<?=$page?>">
    <head>
        <title><?=$title?></title>
    </head>
    <?php include("views/$page.php")?>
</html>
```

Then you can style each page individually.

```
html#login header div#background {
    background-image: url(foo);
}

html#display header div#background {
    background-image: url(bar);
}
```